# Swift 4 - How to structure a json object and using decodable in switch (not working)

Tags: ios, json, swift, decodable

I'm trying to create a structure for the following json object using swift decodable.

```
{
    "template": [

            {
                "id": 8,
                "question": "Favorite Color?",
                "category": "Color",
                "section": "Favorite Colors",
                "is_active": 1,
            },
            [
                {
                    "id": 14,
                    "question_id": 8,
                    "option_name": "Red",
                    "is_active": 1,
                },
                {
                    "id": 16,
                    "question_id": 8,
                    "option_name": "Orange",
                    "is_active": 1,

                }
            ],
            {
                "id": 9,
                "question": "What cars do you drive?",
                "category": "Cars",
                "section": "Favorite Cars",
                "is_active": 1,

            },
            [
                {
                    "id": 15,
                    "question_id": 9,
                    "option_name": "Toyota",
                    "is_active": 1,
                },
                {
                    "id": 18,
                    "question_id": 9,
                    "option_name": "Honda",
                    "is_active": 1,

                },
                {
                    "id": 19,
                    "question_id": 9,
                    "option_name": "BMW",
                    "is_active": 1,

                }
            ]
        ]

}
```

I have some like:

```
public struct GameTemplate:Decodable {
 question:String?
}
 public struct Game:Decodable {
  let template[GameTemplate]
}
```

For some reason when i tried to parse it doesn't work i get an error stating that struct is not a dictionary. I have tried casting the struct value but that didn't work either at this point just need to get a nice and clean json object after is decoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `JSON` format is not consistent.

Just take the first category of `color` :

```
{
"template": [

        {
            "id": 8,
            "question": "Favorite Color?",
            "category": "Color",
            "section": "Favorite Colors",
            "is_active": 1,
        },
        [
            {
                "id": 14,
                "question_id": 8,
                "option_name": "Red",
                "is_active": 1,
            },
            {
                "id": 16,
                "question_id": 8,
                "option_name": "Orange",
                "is_active": 1,

            }
        ],
    ]
}
```

The `template` is an `array` having `dictionary` on 0 index and array on 1 index.
It is decodable in a different way but that's an extra effort.

If possible make the `JSON` data consistent and club categories in one index of array as :

```
{
"template": [

        {
            "id": 8,
            "question": "Favorite Color?",
            "category": "Color",
            "section": "Favorite Colors",
            "is_active": 1,
            "subCategory": [
                       {
                          "id": 14,
                          "question_id": 8,
                          "option_name": "Red",
                          "is_active": 1,
                       },
                       {
                          "id": 16,
                          "question_id": 8,
                          "option_name": "Orange",
                          "is_active": 1,

                       }
              ]
          }
    ]
}
```

and the same way club the different category of cars.

It will be easy for you to decode as:

```
public struct GameTemplate:Decodable {
    question: String?
    subCategory: [SubCategory]
}

public struct SubCategory:Decodable {
    option_name: String?
}

public struct Game:Decodable {
    let template: [GameTemplate]
}
```

Hope you get it what I am trying to explain.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How do i format json when the array producing the format is like this  foreach($question->where('subcategory','color')->get() as $q){
           $values[] = ['question'=>$q,
                        'subcategory' =>  $option->getOptionsWithQuestionID($q->id)];
           
       }